# почему typeScript допускает пустой массив?

Tags: javascript, typescript

по идее он же должен ругаться на `unknownLengthResArray: []` ведь в методе указано что это массив объектов которые должны иметь `key`

```
const args = {
    unknownLengthResArray: [],
    t,
    keyName: 'service',
    namespace: 'services'
}

const sectionBody = unknownLengthDatagridRowSectionBody(args)


interface IInnerObject {
    key: string;
}

type TArgsType = {
    unknownLengthResArray?: IInnerObject[];
    t: any;
    keyName: string;
    namespace: string;
}

type TReturnType = Dictionary<string>[];

export const unknownLengthDatagridRowSectionBody = ({
    unknownLengthResArray,
    t,
    keyName,
    namespace
}: TArgsType): TReturnType => {
    const sectionBody = []
    if(unknownLengthResArray?.length) {
        let section = {}
        let denominator = 3
        unknownLengthResArray.forEach(({ key }, i) => {
            const sectionInfo = {
                [`${t(keyName)} ${i+1}`]: t(`${namespace}:${key}`)
            }
            while(i < denominator){
                section = {...section, ...sectionInfo}
                return
            }
            sectionBody.push(section)
            section = {}
            denominator += denominator
        })
    }
    return sectionBody
}
```

Comment: Все элементы этого массива имеют поле key. Так уж устроена теория. Если вам нужен непустой массив, то возможно вам нужен кортеж (tuple)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в tuple вроде как проблема с количеством элементов, нужно явно задавать

Comment: @yar85, потому что это не массив тогда? :-) А внутри функции используются методы массива

Comment: @Grundy, на это я приведу неоспоримый аргумент против любой критики - "ой, всё" :D Если серьезно, то ответом добавил, милости прошу критиковать более "копипастный" вариант решения. //А коммент удалил, чтобы он не смущал "некопипастностью" подхода.

Comment: @Grundy `[T, …T[]]` вроде как-то так должно работать https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Comment: @AlexeyTen. вроде раньше так нельзя было :)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4GkIE9kDeAUMsgNZ4BcyGYUoA5gNxEC+RRMAriAmMAHsQyGAAo4UKNQDa6bHgA0yAHSq5OXNIC6WgJSESyAG4DgAE2QSoLdp1HbdTZAHpnyAKKSBUO9ILkqZABySFog5FY9FjE-ANxqILIARnDWJX8KeOCyACZUqKA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> почему typeScript допускает пустой массив?

Потому что пустой массив все же является массивом: когда тип *самой переменной* со значением `[]` описан как обычный массив - соответствие типов вполне соблюдается, независимо от типа элементов массива.

> по идее он же должен ругаться на unknownLengthResArray: [] ведь в методе указано что это массив объектов которые должны иметь key

Это ожидание типизации "пустоты", отсутствия значения, которое типизировать невозможно по определению (за исключением спецтипа `never`, который тут по-моему неприменим).
Проще говоря: когда в массиве нет содержимого - нечего проверять на соответствие типов.

---

Как можно объявить тип непустого массива типизированных объектов:

```
interface IInnerObject {
  key: string;
}

interface INonEmptyArray<T> {
  0: T;
  [key: number]: T;
}

type ArrayOfInnerObject = Array<IInnerObject> & INonEmptyArray<IInnerObject>;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKpCaB5ARgKwgTGQG8AoZZAawgE8AuZAZzClAHMBucgX3PKhIsRClQA5APYgAogFsADmDoBBKFDh0APABUAfGUrIADEx08qAbVqNkIAK5zc0ALpme-csoUo1GutgwGFhQeITEyAC8yH6aWuiYOAREYAYAZGhSsorKsdoJIWEpejxedD7IOmoczDrlKNEUVDCSkgD8THmBwUnhYB4C5AjSrMgAbnBQOhCsneqa3YmhyRHRli5cVFvbO7s7APT7yNBQklDIABQcrQAmAJRDIyTD4BDgtTNgc-6LhSska1IyAANnBQUwAOSg6FwCHIXgbKiHY7qM6Xa6Se7kSb%20AAKpzAkm8EHxkgUH1YF3Wd02ezp9IZyGRJzRV1uD0eIFGcFwCG%20CyCSyKq2QliBNkhzEkchQNjhCNpdORIEkKNOUAEMHsIGIwGkyBxmlJhOJpPJ00pQJaqt4ZmqtXqd352lY7BAHAMTWQUAgYHsUBAl2tbQAdMC3hwwAALO7INrIa0huRwBQXSQEKIGdP4EM2WNMdYDIA)

Индексы js-массива непрерывны, поэтому массив с как минимум одним значением всегда имеет элемент с индексом `0`.

При этом, если допустить "пропуск" в значениях, (например) при массиве из двух элементов добавив еще один по индексу `3`, <s>сработает проверка типов - т.е., должна возникать ошибка</s>(а фиг там) TS почему-то не могёт/не хочет проверять тип значений в промежуточных индексах (тут это индекс `2` со значением `undefined`), **такой нюанс надо учитывать**: в идеале, не допускать пропусков, следя за своими константами и явными присваиваниями по индексу; и фильтруя/преобразуя поступающие извне (например, от бэкэнда) входные данные, которые TS не сможет проверить в любом случае.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127274/discussion-on-answer-by-yar85--typescript---).